# runtime error 2467: The expression you entered refers to an object that is closed or doesnt exist

Tags: vba

Hi i am newbie and am trying to get the following code to work from a form button object OnClickEvent():

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()

Dim objOtherTbls As AdditionalData

Set objOtherTbls = Application.CreateAdditionalData

'Identify the tables or querys to export
objOtherTbls.Add "Cycle"
objOtherTbls.Add "Cycle1"


'Here is where the export takes place
Application.ExportXML ObjectType:=acExportTable, _
DataSource:="DACT1", _
DataTarget:="C:\myxml.xml", _
AdditionalData:=objOtherTbls

MsgBox "Export operation completed successfully."
End Sub
```

However I am getting a runtime error 2467:
The expression you entered refers to an object that is closed or doesnt exist.

The debugger is pointing to this line:
'AdditionalData:=objOtherTbls'
can anyone helP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure it should be

```
Set objOtherTbls = Application.CreateAdditionalData()
```

and not

```
Set objOtherTbls = Application.CreateAdditionalData
```

as you are calling a method.

Comment: Does `DACT1` refer to a valid Access table?

Comment: DACT1 is the database object ie DACT1.accdb

Comment: It should be the table you want to export as you specified the type to table with `ObjectType:=acExportTable`.

Comment: This works however 2 questions: 
(1) whichever table I assign to the DataSource variable is duplicated in the output xml- how do i stop this?
(2) Is there an easy way to wrap each row of output in an xml root element eg DACTRecord below:


<DACTRecord>
<Cycle>
<AA>0</AA>
<BB>2013-06-01</BB>
<CC>150.123</CC>
</Cycle>
<DACTRecord/>
<DACTRecord>
<Cycle1>
<EE>0</EE>
<FF>2013-06-01</FF>
<GG>150.123</GG>
</Cycle1>
<DACTRecord/>

Comment: @user2576383 The table will be duplicated if you specify it both as DataSource and add it with `objOtherTbls.Add`. The second part I'm afraid I can't help you with as I don't know Access well enough.

Comment: Ok. i have removed 'objOtherTbls.Add "Cycle"' but left it as the DataSource. This works. Although this is kind of why i originally expected to point the dataSource to the DACT1.accdb. thanks again jpw